# Run magento site in subdirectory

Tags: htaccess, magento-1.9.2.1, 301-redirect

I have magento in subfolder and running very well like below url:-

```
www.site.com/myshop/
```

but for SEO purpose I want to run my magento site without `myshop` folder.
I want to run my site like `www.site.com/category.html` instead of `www.site.com/myshop/category.html`

How can I do this using htaccess. please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: you should config server root from your virtualhost config on your apache webserver

Comment: I am not much know about server please explain bit more